# Do chat stars manually unstarred by the room's owner still count towards the badge?

Tags: support, badges, chat

Can the room owners directly affect this badge?
Or are the stars "permanent" even if they get cleared off the star list manually?

For reference, the **Outspoken** badge is awarded for:

> Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users

Comment: You might be able to check this for yourself now :)